# Timed Download csv file from a website everyday to specific folder

Tags: html, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to automatically download the csv file from the below mentioned website everyday in the morning to a specific folder. Have managed to put together the following code but I'm getting an xpath error. Also it would be helpful if the download happens without opening and closing the browser(i.e in silent mode)

````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
import pandas as pd
import time

#your website url
site = 'https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Forth_Results.aspx'


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
            "download.default_directory": f"C:\\Data\\downloads\\", # IMPORTANT - ENDING SLASH V IMPORTANT
            "directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)


#your driver path
s=Service("C:\\python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=options)

#passing website url
driver.get(site)

#wait until whole sites load
time.sleep(8)

#click download icon using xpath
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/a/i").click()
#closing browser
driver.close()
#reading Results.csv from defalut download directory
df = pd.read_csv("c:/Data/downloads/Results.csv")
df```


**Getting the following error:**

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63140/devtools/browser/42551ed0-b41c-432d-bff1-6de3ae46b084
[11624:12196:1008/102652.452:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(225)] [10:26:52.451] USB: usb_service_win.cc:415 Could not read device interface GUIDs: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\BSE_reults.py", line 33, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/a/i").click()
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
````

Comment: Did you use ChatGPT to generate this code?

Comment: So you did not write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except I have strong feeling, that you used ChapGPT to generate your code, I'll help you.

Download button has unique id attribute `lnkDownload`.
`id` attribute is usually unique, so there is high possibility that you can rely on it. (Use dev console to be sure it is)

If `id` attribute is not auto-generated, it's good practice to use it first.

Getting element by id is one of the fastest operation in getting WebElements.

So, to locate element you don't need full XPATH.
Tuple should look like `(By.ID, "lnkDownload")`

Second point - new Selenium versions don't have method `find_element_by_xpath`, it was deprecated.

Current syntax is `driver.find_element(by, locator)`.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# your imports and code

driver.get("https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Forth_Results.aspx")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "lnkDownload"))).click()
```

Comment: This is a good answer but some clarifications: 1. The HTML spec states that an ID should be unique on the page but there are many sites where this is not true. I still verify that the ID Is unique before using it. This can be easily done in the devtools console using a CSS selector, `$$("#lnkDownload")`. 2. When running a Selenium script, you aren't going to see any speed difference between an ID or CSS selector or XPath. In fact, the ID locator is converted to a CSS selector by Selenium. There might be a few ms difference but it's not going to be something you are going to notice.

Comment: @JeffC 1. Yep, I agree. Some sites don't use common practices and can contain several elements with same id. There is high posibility that id would be unique, anyway, as you mentioned, it is always shown number of elements by locator in dev tools. Corrected in answer.
2. I agree, that searching by id, using xpath or css wouldn't show big difference. I meant in general, that searching by id is quicker than by non-id xpath or css selector. (Maybe something changed and it is not true now, 6 years ago, when I made a comparsion last time, locating element by id was quickest operation)

Comment: On my last projects during last 6 years I have ability to assign locators by myself, so usually elements have `data-testid` or `data-automation-id` or `data-hook` that are used for automation. If I don't have ability to assign locator, I search for `id`, then for `name` / `role` / some attribute that seems unique for element or elements group, so the question of "what is quicker" was irrelevant. :)